# Why is my object desctructoring throwing a no string index signature error in typescript?

Tags: object, typescript, destructuring

Given an object

```
const appConfig: {
    brands: {...},
    market: {...},
}
```

I try to destructure it in typescript via:

```
const {brand} =  appConfig.brand;
```

Which fails via:

```
src/partner/transform.ts(17,12): error TS2459: Type 'IBrandConfig' has no property 'brand' and no string index signature.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a faulty object desctructor syntax. These will work as expected:

```
const {brand} =  appConfig;
const {brand, market} =  appConfig;
```

As they are a shortcut for:

```
const brand =  appConfig.brand;
const market =  appConfig.market;
```